# Spring boot devtools load twice of a class and cause LinkageError

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, classloader

IDE is Idea, Spring boot project have `META-INF/spring-devtools.properties`, the content is

```
restart.include.dozer=/dozer-5.5.1.jar
```

when run project throw below exception

```
2015-12-03 12:02:49,491 [restartedMain] INFO  org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2015-12-03 12:02:49,494 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dozerBeanMapper' defined in class path resource [com/foo/common/CommonConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.dozer.Mapper]: Factory method 'dozerBeanMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/dozer/DozerBeanMapper"
2015-12-03 12:02:49,517 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dozerBeanMapper' defined in class path resource [com/foo/common/CommonConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.dozer.Mapper]: Factory method 'dozerBeanMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/springframework/boot/devtools/restart/classloader/RestartClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/dozer/DozerBeanMapper"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

What strange is when run the project in Eclipse, no above problem.
Add `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` configuration in idea, I found dozer is loaded twice.

```
9569 [Loaded org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper from file:/C:/Users/otto/.m2/repository/net/sf/dozer/dozer/5.5.1/dozer-5.5.1.jar]

9618 [Loaded org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper from file:/C:/Users/otto/.m2/repository/net/sf/dozer/dozer/5.5.1/dozer-5.5.1.jar]
```

Now I don't know how to locate the reason of this problem?

Comment: Can you please share a small sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson Hey I created a minimalism sample--https://gist.github.com/zhugw/63e98f99098156e8173a. Run FooAplication, you could generate that error.

Comment: Could you please push the actual project into a Git repo somewhere? I'd like to be sure I'm running _exactly_ the same code as you and piecing it together from a gist means that might not be the case.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson  Sorry! I had uploaded that project to github--https://github.com/zhugw/sample.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some critical information in the README of the project that you shared that's not included in the question:

> Download sample project then import this project to eclipse, closed bar project then run FooApplication you could get below error

Closing the bar project mean that its classes will not be eligible for restart. This means that they will be loaded by the main class loader rather than the restart class loader. The code in bar depends on Dozer, but you've configured DevTools so that Dozer's classes will be loaded by the restart class loader:

```
restart.include.dozer=/dozer-5.5.1.jar
```

It's not clear to me why you've configured things this way. Your sample works fine for me if I delete `spring-devtools.properties`. Perhaps the sample doesn't illustrate the problem that caused you to apply that configuration?

If you do need this configuration and you don't want to have the bar project open in Eclipse then you also need to configure bar to be included in restarts so that both it and Dozer upon which it depends are loaded by the restart class loader:

```
restart.include.dozer=/dozer-5\.5\.1\.jar
restart.include.bar=/bar-1\.0-SNAPSHOT\.jar
```

Comment: Thnaks! As why have spring-devtools.properties, please see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4636

Comment: and I was a little worried that contents in `spring-devtools.properties` will constantly increase

Comment: see my post above, `DozerBeanMapper` is loaded twice. Where are it loaded? one place is in bar project : `private final static DozerBeanMapper dozer = new DozerBeanMapper();`, another is `@Bean
  public Mapper fooDozerBeanMapper()` in FooApplication. Am I right? which one is base calssloader? because I have specified explcitily `restart.include.dozer=/dozer-5\.5\.1\.jar`, why they are not both loaded by restart classloader?

Comment: The bar project is loaded by the base class loader. This happens because the project is closed in Eclipse so DevTools knows that its classes won't change and therefore that it won't trigger a restart. When `new DozerBeanMapper` in the bar project runs it loads the `DozerBeanMapper` class. It has to be loaded by the base class loader as that's the class loader that loaded all of bar's classes. There's nothing Spring Boot can do about that, it's just how class loading works in Java. For Bar to load Dozer using the restart class loader, Bar also has to be loaded by the restart class loader.

Comment: So if bar is loaded by base classloader(e.g. closed in eclipse), all its dependencies are loaded by base,although you explicitly specify some dependency(e.g. dozer) should be loaded by restart in `spring-devtools.properties`. But if it is loader by restart classloader(e.g. bar is opened in eclipse), situation is diff, this time its dependencies are loaded by base classloader, so you have to explicitly specify which dependency should be loaded by restart.  Am I right?